# List all activities of an app

Tags: applications

I have an Android phone which is *not* rooted.

Is there any way I can obtain/export a list of all installed packages ***with their available activities***?

ADWLauncher has an activity picker in its custom shortcut feature.
It lists things like:

```
Calculator
  Calculator(.Calculator)
Camera
  Camera(.Camera)
  Camcorder(.VideoCamera)
  Camera(.Camera_dual)
  Camera(.VideoCamera_dual) ...
```

I have apps which generate a list of installed packages, but how can I get something like this showing all the activities?

Comment: I'm curious what you want to accomplish with this. How does it help you to know what the activity names are in each package?

Comment: It's partly curiousity and trying to better understand my phone and the apps. But my larger goal is to use some of these in Tasker programming.

Comment: You can use ROM Toolbox -> App Manager -> long click on app -> advanced freeze -> it will show you all registered activities, services, broadcast receivers for that app.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at all Activities of an app by using [QuickShortcutMaker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sika524.android.quickshortcut) app. It's quite a funny app which can make a shortcut to specified activity of any program, so you can even launch those hidden ones.

Answer (score 0):

Install [Apex Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.anddoes.launcher) from the Play Store. Open the Widgets and you can find a widget named **Activities** (with blue Apex Launcher icon). Place the widget in your home screen and open it. You will see the list of all app's activities listed.

[image: Screenshot_Apex_Activites_screen]

<sub>Screenshot - Click to enlarge image</sub>