# Why aren't my app icons showing up after installed?

Tags: applications, launcher, app-icons

I have Moto X Style phone having Android 6.0.

Today I installed "Stereo Bluetooth Headset SBH52" app on my phone, but I am not able to open this app because there is no app launcher icon in the launcher. In Play Store, it's also showing *Uninstall* button only. I am able to see the app in *Setting > Apps*. Here, only *Uninstall* button is enabled.

I have one more app "Exchange Server" which is there in Apps list, but the icon is not available in the launcher.

I also have restarted the phone. I removed the SD card, then again installed these app from Play Store, but still the issue is there.

Why are there no app icons showing up?

Comment: Related/dupe: [Why are some apps hidden and how to unhide them](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/38209/why-are-some-apps-hidden-and-how-to-unhide-them)

Answer (score 2):

Not all apps have explicit launchers (or app icon).

Take an example from [Stereo Bluetooth Headset SBH52](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sonymobile.smartconnect.raphael) app:

> **This application will not be visible in your phone's home screen**. Access application settings via Smart Connect (LiveWare™ Manager), or via your phone's status bar.
>
> <sup>(Emphasis added)</sup>

As for Exchange Server (or Exchange *Services* on Nexus stock ROM), it's only a back-end service used for communicating with Exchange server, with stock E-Mail app as its front-end UI.

Another example is Google PDF Viewer, where it's only prompted when opening a PDF file. (see [How to open Google PDF Viewer app?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/121079/how-to-open-google-pdf-viewer-app/121085#121085)).

If you want to force open the app, you might be interested in [List all activities of an app](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7828/list-all-activities-of-an-app).

Comment: @Andrew...Thanks 4 ur reply...
After connecting  "Stereo Bluetooth Headset SBH52" device the app is not launching and because of this some of the feature is not working.
I tried in lower version of Android phone and after installing the app, I am able to see icon in launcher.